# Calling a Vba script in a HTML5 page

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer

I create a script in Vba allowing to compare reports in Word and I would like to create a page in HTML allowing to launch the Vba script after clicking a button.

When I try to do that, I obtain the message "*ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined*" in Firefox and Chrome. If I try the same on IE, I obtain the error "'myFunction' is undefined".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Reports Comparison</title>
    <script type="text/vbscript" src="myScript.vbs"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" value="Test" onClick="myFunction()">
  </body>
</html>
```

myFunction is correctly defined in the file myScript.vbs :

```
Sub myFunction ()
    Dim strFolderA As String
    Dim strFolderB As String
    Dim strFolderC As String
    Dim strFileSpec As String
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim objDocA As Word.Document
    Dim objDocB As Word.Document
    Dim objDocC As Word.Document
    strFolderA = InputBox("Enter path to base documents:")
    strFolderB = InputBox("Enter path to new documents:")
    strFolderC = InputBox("Enter path for document comparisons to be saved:")
    strFileSpec = "*.docx"
    strFileName = Dir(strFolderA & strFileSpec)
    Do While strFileName <> vbNullString
        Set objDocA = Documents.Open(strFolderA & strFileName)
        Set objDocB = Documents.Open(strFolderB & strFileName)
        Application.CompareDocuments _
            OriginalDocument:=objDocA, _
            RevisedDocument:=objDocB, _
            Destination:=wdCompareDestinationNew
        objDocA.Close
        objDocB.Close
        Set objDocC = ActiveDocument
        objDocC.SaveAs FileName:=strFolderC & strFileName
        objDocC.Close SaveChanges:=False
        strFileName = Dir
    Loop
    Set objDocA = Nothing
    Set objDocB = Nothing
End Sub
```

Could you please help me to do that?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VBScript can only be used in Internet Explorer. And even then it won't work by default, you have to enable "Enterprise Mode" to enable backwards compatibility and various other flags to allow the browser access to the file system. You also can't work with a Word document like this without some extra legwork since `Word` won't be defined here.

There is a new Javascript API that you might be able to leverage instead but again this isn't for use in the context of a browser. But it would let you add some functionality to word itself.

https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/javascript-api-for-office